Unable to have same source and destination for an data sync task
I am trying to have a same source and destination for a data sync task on AWS.
Data sync has to happen between 2 directories inside the same efs.
But terraform is hitting a error.
creating DataSync Task: InvalidRequestException: Destination location cannot be same as source location.

This task can be achievable by manual, but still i would like to do it via IAC.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.
